# @ExceptionHandler not being invoked

Tags: spring, exception

After some time researching and trying different things I still cannot get my @ExceptionHandler to be invoked in my jUnit integration test. Please, help me understand why?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someURL", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView batchUpload(@RequestBody final String xml, @RequestParam boolean replaceAll)
    throws IOException, URISyntaxException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, UnmarshallingFailureException
{
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
DomainClass xmlDomainClass;

try
{
    xmlDomainClass = (DomainClass) castorMarshaller.unmarshal(source);
}
catch (UnmarshallingFailureException me)
{
    // some logging. this gets executed
    throw me;
}
```

.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public ModelAndView handleUnmarshallingExceptions(Throwable th)
{
// never executes anything in here
return new ModelAndView( /*some parameters */ );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Spring: RESTful controllers and error handling](http://blog.cuttleworks.com/2011/12/spring-restful-controllers-and-error-handling/) helped me, my problem was the lack of this:

```
@Component
public class AnnotatedExceptionResolver extends AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver{
  public AnnotatedExceptionResolver() {
    setOrder(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer - I couldn't figure out why my @ExceptionHandler was being ignored but figured it might be related to the fact that I'm also using a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. This fixed the issue for me.